# Regex Pattern to Identify the restAPI's resourcePath

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-2.7

I need to have some python regex to determine the 'Short Name' based on the 'URL' string.

I have tried the below RegEx Pattern, but it is not working for the below cases.

**CASE-1 :**

Input URL for 'Get Accounts' can be

```
"GET /env/org/v1/insurance/accounts"
"GET /env/org/v1/insurance/accounts?page&page-size"
```

Note : Here the query parameters may or may not be present .

Regex-1:

```
^GET /env/org/v1/insurance/accounts(\?)?(\w)?$
```

**CASE-2:**

Input URL for 'Get Transactions' can be

```
"GET /env/org/v1/insurance/accounts/B001E2E0-7E5/transactions"
"GET /env/org/v1/insurance/accounts/6286CDC4-E2B/transactions?oldest-time"
```

Note : Here the 'TransactionID' varies everytime and query parameters may or may not be present .

Regex-2:

```
^GET /env/org/v1/insurance/accounts/[A-Za-Z0-9\-]+/transactions(\?)?(\w)?$
```

**CASE-3 :**

Input string for 'Get Single Transaction' can be

```
"GET /env/org/v1/insurance/accounts/091CCD40-2E7/transactions/091CCD40-1E7?page"
```

So that I can use in the Python code as below:

```
import re

def get_short_name(str):
    if(re.match(regex_1,str):
        return 'Get Accounts'
    elif(re.match(regex_2,str):
        return 'Get Transactions'
    elif(re.match(regex_3,str):
        return 'Get Single Transactions'
    else:
        return str
```

Comment: Do you need just  the url excluding the query parameters ?

Comment: Remove the `GET` and use [urllib.parse.urlparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse) to get all the url components.

Comment: I need a regex pattern to match the URL, Sometimes the query parameters may or may not be present .

Comment: @Mandy8055 I need to include this regex in the python code as above

Comment: @Mandy8055 I have included the sample python code logic too.

Comment: @Mandy8055 The above regex is not working for me. Unable to figure out what's wrong with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to break the regex in three parts; you may try something like:

```
1. ^GET \/sit1\/org\/v1\/insurance\/accounts(?:\?.*)?$
2. ^GET \/sit1\/org\/v1\/insurance\/accounts\/.*$
3. ^GET \/sit1\/org\/v1\/insurance\/accounts\/.*\/transactions\/.*$
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`^, $`** - Represents start and end of line respectively.
- **`GET \/sit1\/org\/v1\/insurance\/accounts`** - Matches literally with escaping `/`.
- **`(?:\?.*)?`** - Represents a [**non-capturing group**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) matching everything after `\?`. The outer `?` denotes a quantifier which matches this whole pattern 0 or 1 time i.e. Makes it optional.
- **`\/.*`** - In the second regex; it represents match everything after `accounts/`.
- **`\/.*\/transactions\/.*`** - In the third regex; it denotes after accounts; capture everything till `/transactions/` and after that capture everything till the end of line.

**Sample Implementation in python:**

```
import re

regex_1 = r"^GET \/sit1\/org\/v1\/insurance\/accounts(?:\?.*)?$"
regex_2 = r"^GET \/sit1\/org\/v1\/insurance\/accounts\/.*$"
regex_3= r"^GET \/sit1\/org\/v1\/insurance\/accounts\/.*\/transactions\/.*$"

test_str_accounts = "GET /sit1/org/v1/insurance/accounts?page&page-size"
test_str_transactions = "GET /sit1/org/v1/insurance/accounts/6286CDC4-E2B/transactions?oldest-time"
test_str_single_transactions = "GET /sit1/org/v1/insurance/accounts/091CCD40-2E7/transactions/091CCD40-1E7?page"



def get_short_name(str):
    if re.match(regex_1,str):
        return 'Get Accounts'
    elif re.match(regex_3,str):
        return 'Get Single Transactions'
    elif re.match(regex_2,str):
        return 'Get Transactions'
    else:
        return str
    
print(get_short_name(test_str_accounts))
print(get_short_name(test_str_transactions))
print(get_short_name(test_str_single_transactions))
```

You can find the sample run of the above implementation in [**here.**](https://onlinegdb.com/HJ9HlN71D)

**NOTE: Please do note the order of if statements. Transaction 3 is checked first.**

Comment: Can you pls explain   (?:\?.*)?   Does it checks for query parameters only

Comment: Please give me a moment; I'm adding the necessary details. Now also it is not working as expected; but I'll fix it in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `urlparse` and use `str.endswith`

**Ex:**

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

data = ['GET /sit1/org/v1/insurance/accounts', 'GET /sit1/org/v1/insurance/accounts?page&page-size', 'GET /sit1/org/v1/insurance/accounts/B001E2E0-7E5/transactions', 'GET /sit1/org/v1/insurance/accounts/6286CDC4-E2B/transactions?oldest-time']

for url in data:
    o = urlparse(url.split()[1])
    print(o.path)
    if o.path.endswith('accounts'):
        print('accounts')
    if o.path.endswith('transactions'):
        print('transactions')
```

**Output:**

```
/sit1/org/v1/insurance/accounts
/sit1/org/v1/insurance/accounts
/sit1/org/v1/insurance/accounts/B001E2E0-7E5/transactions
/sit1/org/v1/insurance/accounts/6286CDC4-E2B/transactions
```

Comment: but how to ignore the 'transactionId' in the middle of the url ?

Comment: sorry i do not understand...why do you need the transactionId ignored?

Comment: I have added CASE-3 in the question, for clarify on what i mean by 'transactionId'